# Linq to Entities and Drop Downs

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am loading the values into a drop down using linq to entities.

I need the first value in the drop down to read "Select" with value of 0 or "".

How can I add that value to my linq query or to the drop down in asp.net forms.

My current code:

```
    'Payment Types
    Dim SourcePaymentTypes = (From s In db.PayoutAdjustmentTypes.OrderBy("Name") Select s).ToList
    CmbReason.DataSource = SourcePaymentTypes
    CmbReason.DataTextField = "Name"
    CmbReason.DataValueField = "AdjustmentTypeID"
    CmbReason.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `.Add()` a `new PayoutAdjustmentType { Name = "Select", AdjustmentTypeId = 0 }` record to your `SourcePaymentTypes` variable before you set it as the `DataSource` of your `CmbReason`

(Apologies it's in C# syntax, but I'm sure you can translate)